# ACME tablet boot loops when trying to flash a custom ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop

I was trying to install a custom ROM on an ACME TB714 tablet and it kind of went wrong. The tablet is set on a boot loop which occurs on the manufacturer logo. The tablet has no volume buttons or a reset button and I don't know how to enter recovery mode and is also rooted.

My goal was to upgrade it from Android KitKat to Lollipop. I tried this using the TWRP apk.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem and achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to open up the tablet, power it on, and shunt pins 41-42-43. I followed the tutorial from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-vtH4cZalk) but I used a paper clip instead of a screw.

**Warning**: only use this method if everything else fails.